# Get-AzureLocation not showing all locations my subscription has access to

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell

I'm using a [6 month student Azure Pass](https://www.microsoftazurepass.com/azureu) subscription, which allows me to successfully create a storage account in any of the Azure locations using the web portal:

[image]

However, when I try to create a storage account using PowerShell (using the same Azure account and subscription) it won't let me create a storage account in North Europe or West Europe. So if I try:

```
New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName mystorageaccountname -Location "North Europe" -Type Standard_LRS
```

I get:

> New-AzureStorageAccount : BadRequest: The location constraint is not
>   valid

Using the Get-AzureLocation command confirms that I only seem to have access to 4 regions - East US, Central US, Southeast Asia and Japan West

```
Get-AzureLocation | select Name

Name          
----          
East US       
Central US    
Southeast Asia
Japan West
```

I've double-checked that my powershell session is using the same Azure login and subscription that I'm using in the portal (I login using Add-AzureAccount then use Select-AzureSubscription to set my subscription to "Azure Pass").

This seems really strange to me, does anyone have any ideas? Why would I be allowed to create a storage account in North Europe using the portal, but not using powershell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The portal is using the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) to create the storage account, whereas your PowerShell is using the "Classic" ASM mode.  The ARM analogous PowerShell command would be "New-Azure**Rm**StorageAccount".  Note the "Rm" (for Resource Manager) in the PowerShell command.

Comment: And here's a good overview of using PowerShell with ARM:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/